# Owin selfhost - dont allow connections from external machines

Tags: owin, self-host-webapi

I have a c# app that runs as "server" for a client app (Electron).

The c# does the data crunching and serves the data over HTTP to the JS client.
The webendpoint is implmented using Microsoft Owin and WebAPI.

It works very well, however, I do not want the port to be bound on the network interface at all, only on the "loopback".

The binding is done as described in owin docs as

```
WebApp.Start<MyConfig>("http://localhost:10000");
```

I choose a high port number to avoid being Admin.

This works well, however, the port is open from outside too, albeit, http requests from outside are rejected with bad request (which is good for me), but i dont want to bind at all.

I cant seem to find anyway to do this, any idea ?

Comment: I should add that doing so with http://127.0.0.1 gives error ...